# redirect to servlet class file using jquery

Tags: jquery, servlets, redirect

I have used jquery-1.11.2.min.js and chrome 40.0.2214.115

In user registration form if anyone of the field is empty i want to show the alert message to user otherwise redirect to the servlet class file, in that servlet class i wrote the db connection for insert the user details.

My user registration html code is

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
        {
    $("#submitid").click(function()
      {
        var fname=$("#firstname2").val();
        var lanme=$("#lastname2").val();
        var email=$("#email2").val();
        var mobileno=$("#mobileno").val();
        var username=$("#username").val();
        var pass=$("#password").val();
        if(fname==''||lname==''||email=''||mobileno==''||username==''||pass=='')
            {
            alert("Enter all fields");
            $("#userform").focus();

            }
        else
            window.location.href("Userdetailsins.java");
            });
        });</script>
</head>

<body>

<form class="stdform stdform2" method="post"  id="userform">
<label>First Name</label>
 <input type="text" name="userfname" id="firstname2" class="longinput" />
<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="userlname" id="lastname2" class="longinput" />
<label>Email</label>
<input type="text" name="mailid" id="email2" class="longinput" 
<label>Mobile no</label>
 <input type="text" name="mobno" id="mobileno" class="longinput" 
 <label>User name </label>
 <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="longinput" />
 <label>User Password </label>
 <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="longinput" /></span>                     
 <input type="reset" value="Reset Button" />
 <input type="submit"  id="submitid" name="submitid" value="Next"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't show alert message when the fields are empty and doesn't redirect to another form. Even i tried with another html file to redirect it doesn't work. for redirection i have followed the guidelines shown below

```
//$(location).attr('href',"http://www.google.com");
        //window.open("next.html");
        //$("#submitform").focus();

         //$(window.location).attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');

        //window.navigator("next.html");
        //self.location="next.html";

    //top.location="next.html";
    //var url="www.google.com"
        //window.location.replace(url);

    //window.location.href("next.html");
    window.open("next.html");
```

The window.open() method works but i don't want to open as a separate window i just to redirect. Please anyone help to solve this.

Thanks....

Comment: by using this u getting any error window.location.href("next.html"); @Asha

Comment: Thanks@coding cracker I didn't got any error. the form reside on the same page didn't redirect to next.html.

Comment: on click u need to redirect to another page right ?

Comment: Try my answer asha it will work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
function nextredirect(){
  window.location.href = 'next.html';
}
```

Jquery

```
$('#submitid').click(function(){

if($('#firstname2').val() == ""){
alert('Please enter the first name');
}else{
 window.location.href = 'next.html';
}
});
```

Html

```
 <input type="button"  id="submitid" name="submitid" value="Next" onclick="nextredirect()"/>
```

Comment: Thanks it works in onclick event. but i want to validate the form using jquery then only i will redirect to next page... is there any way in jquery? @Coding cracker

Comment: one more request coding cracker your code works when using input type as button but the input type="submit" the form doesn't redirect. please help to solve this problem... @coding cracker

Comment: $("#here your submit button id").submit(function(e){
    return false;
});

Comment: else u can $('#formid').submit instead of `window.location.href = 'next.html'` this Asha got it ?

Comment: $(document).ready(function()
  {
 $('#submitid').submit(function(e){

  if($('#firstname2').val() == ""){
  alert('Please enter the first name');
  }else{
   window.location.href = 'upload.html';
   //$("#uploadid").submit;
  }

  });
 return false;
  });       i try like that but it doesn't work...

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#submitid').submit(function(e){ 
 if($('#firstname2').val() == ""){
 alert('Please enter the first name'); 
 return false; 
 }else{ 
 window.location.href = 'upload.html'; 
 //$("#uploadid").submit; 
 } 
 }); 
 });` check this asha

Comment: nice work... I just added the return false stmt in else part of the click event of submit button it works well. Thank you very much for your more help to solve my problem....@coding cracker

Comment: im glad to help you im Irfan @Asha